# Salmon Run Weapons are Green Question Marks

Tags: splatoon-2

For the next Salmon Run shift, 2/17 3:00 a.m. to 2/18 3:00 p.m., there are only green question marks instead of weapons. What does this mean? Are these random weapons or are they just hidden?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the employee handbook available on grizzco industries, you can nothing more than just the usual:

> All equipment necessary for collecting Power Eggs (weapons, gear, ink tanks) will be provided by the company. There is no need for employees to prepare anything themselves, so first-timers needn't worry.

However, the [splatoon wiki](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Grizzco_Industries) says that during two times period salmon runs also provided a [Grizzco Blaster](https://splatoonwiki.org/wiki/Grizzco_Blaster) and a Grizzco Brella.

During gameplay, I could notice that there are way more than 4 weapons available, but they seen to be a limited amount. Also, the Grizzco Brella is also available today.